# Is it appropriate to report standard error obtained by bootstrap when observed statistics is away from the median of the bootstrapped distribution?

Tags: r, bootstrap, standard-error

I quantified a statistics that measure the percentage of covariation between set of variables, lets say Int, across 3 groups (for each group Int was calculated). Int ranges from 0 to 100.

Afterwards I used bootstrap in order to obtain some measure of variability of the Int within each group (resampling was with replacement within each group).

Because I can not pass all the data and complex cod for the Int, below I **generated (mimic) the pattern** of the results that I obtained after bootstrap:

```
  set.seed (50)

# here "Int.boot.dist" mimic bootstrap distribution that I obtained
  Int.boot.dist <- rnorm (n = 100, mean = 50, sd = 15)

# boxplot     
  boxplot (Int.boot.dist, main = "Boxplot of bootstrapped distribution of the Int", 
  ylab = "integration", ylim = c (0, 100))

# mimic observed mean
  obs.mean <- sample [order (sample, decreasing = T)][3]

  points (obs.mean, cex = 2.5, lwd = 3, pch = 4, col = "red")
  legend ("topleft", legend = "observed mean", cex = 1, col = "red", pch = 4)
```

[image: Figure 1.]

As you can note, observed Int is almost like outlier and considerably far away from bootstrapped mean or median.

```
   ## plot (as a bar where height correspond to the observed Int) along with standard error    

           plot (Int.boot.dist, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c (0, 100), 
               xlab =  "group1", ylab = "integration")
            x <- c (0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5)
            y <- c (0, 0, obs.mean, obs.mean)
            polygon (x, y, border = "black", col = "gray")

    ## calculate standard error
    sd <- sqrt(var(sample))
            y0 <- obs.mean-sd
            y1 <- obs.mean+sd

            segments (1, y0, 1, y1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
            legend ("topleft", legend = "SDM", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

Second graph shows bar that corresponds to the observed Int value and red line shows standard error obtained by bootstrap.

[image: Figure 2.]

**Q1:** Is it appropriate to report standard error (e.g. second graph) when observed statistics depart from mean or median of bootstrapped distribution?

**Q2:** What does such pattern tell us about the data and is it appropriate to compare such statistics at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have demonstrated that your estimator for `Int` is probably biased; that is, the expected value of repeated sample estimates of `Int` is different from the population value of `Int`. The bootstrap was originally devised in part as a way to estimate such bias. Also, note that with your `Int` scale limited to 100 as a top value, there is no way for your `Int` values to have a normal distribution and that your confidence intervals are unlikely to be symmetric about the center value.

You don't specify how you calculate `Int` or the nature of the underlying data, but you should know that the standard Pearson correlation coefficient is a [biased estimate of the population correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) even in the idealized case of variables having a bivariate normal distribution. So it's not surprising that your sample estimate of `Int`, which seems to have some sort of relation to a correlation coefficient, is also biased.

You should take advantage of already developed tools to solve your problem. The `boot.ci` function in the R `boot` package provides several types of estimates of confidence intervals. For your situation, with a biased estimator and a necessarily skewed distribution of your `Int` values (as they can't exceed 100), you would want to use the "bca" type of confidence interval. [This Cross Validated Page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63652/28500) goes into more detail about bootstrapping, with links to further information.

Comment: thanks for the answer and suggestions, I will add soon more info regarding symmetry of distribution and the way of how Int was calculated.