# How can I obtain a confidence interval for the difference between two probabilities from a binary logistic regression model?

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, proportion

I saw this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411175/confidence-interval-for-difference-between-two-predicted-probabilities-in-r), but it doesn't have a clear answer.

Suppose I have a simple logistic regression model with binary $x:$

$$\log(p/(1-p)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$$

Then I know:

$$p/(1-p) = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x}$$

and

$$p = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x}/(1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x})$$

So if $x=0,$ then the model becomes:

$$\log(p/(1-p)) = \beta_0$$

and if $x=1,$ then the model becomes:

$$\log(p/(1-p)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1$$

To obtain a confidence interval for $p$ when $x=0,$ I did this:

```
model <- glm(y~., family=binomial(), data)

#For x=0
Bigma = vcov(model)
sig = sqrt(Bigma[1,1])

logit_p = coef(model)[1][[1]] #The intercept

theta_L = logit_p - 1.96*sig
theta_U = logit_p + 1.96*sig

p_L = plogis(theta_L) 
p_U = plogis(theta_U)
```

The confidence interval is (p_L, p_U).

Then a confidence interval for p when x=1:

```
sig_x1 = sqrt(Bigma[1,1] + Bigma[2,2] + 2*Bigma[1,2])

logit_p_x1 = coef(model)[1][[1]] + coef(model)[2][[1]] #beta_0 + beta_1

theta_L_x1 = logit_p_x1 - 1.96*sig_x1
theta_U_x1 = logit_p_x1 + 1.96*sig_x1

p_L_x1 = plogis(theta_L_x1) 
p_U_x1 = plogis(theta_U_x1)
```

The confidence interval is (p_L_x1, p_U_x1).

Now I would like a confidence interval for the difference in probability of success when $x=0$ and $x=1.$

I can obtain the point estimate of the difference:

$$p_{x_1} - p_{x_0} = [e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1} - e^{\beta_0}]/[(1+e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1})(1+e^{\beta_0})]$$

I know the next step is to compute the standard error of the difference, but I don't know how to do this.

**Question**: What is the formula and R code for a confidence interval for the difference in the two probabilities when $x=0$ and when $x=1?$

Comment: You would likely need to use the delta method for this.  Is there some reason why examining the coefficient of $\beta_1$ is not sufficient?

Comment: Okay thanks for starting this off! What is the delta method and how do I use it? And why would examining the coefficient for beta_1 give me what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The delta method states

$$ \operatorname{Var}(g(X)) = [g'(X)]^2 \operatorname{Var}(X)$$

Because this problem involves two parameters, we can extend this to the multivariate delta method

$$ =\nabla g^T \,  \Sigma \, \nabla g $$

Here,

$$ g = \left[e^{\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}}-e^{\beta_{0}}\right] /\left[\left(1+e^{\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}}\right)\left(1+e^{\beta_{0}}\right)\right] $$

and $\Sigma$ is the variance covariance matrix from your model.  $\nabla g$ is...gross.  I'm not going to do that by hand, and computer algebra while fast yields a mess of symbols.  You can however use autodifferentiation compute the gradient.  Once you calculate the variance, then its simply your estimate of the difference in probs plus/minus 1.96 times the standard deviation (root of the variance).  Caution, this approach will yield answers below 0 or above 1.

We can do this in R in the following way (note you need to install the `autodiffr` package).

```
library(autodiffr)

g = function(b)  (exp(b[1] + b[2]) - exp(b[1])) / ((1+ exp(b[1] + b[2]))*(1+exp(b[1])))

x = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
eta = -0.8 + 0.2*x
p = plogis(eta)
y = rbinom(100, 1, p)

model = glm(y~x, family=binomial())
Bigma = vcov(model)

grad_g = makeGradFunc(g)
nabla_g = grad_g(coef(model))


se = as.numeric(sqrt(nabla_g %*% Bigma %*% nabla_g))


estimate = diff(predict(model, newdata=list(x=c(0, 1)), type='response'))

estimate + c(-1, 1)*1.96*se
```

Repeating this procedure for this modest example shows that the resulting confidence interval has near nominal coverage, which is a good thing, but I imagine things would become worse as the probabilities approach 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you Demetri, this looks wonderful. I'm curious about the statement "Caution, this approach will yield answers below 0 or above 1.". Is there another approach that would not have this problem?

Comment: @StatsSorceress  I may have misspoken.  The difference between two probabilities can only, be between -1 and 1.  This method does not guarantee that the estimated differences in the resulting confidence interval respect this bound.  That being said, you can still use it.  Just be sure to check the confidence interval only has values between -1 and 1.

Comment: Why use this method when `glm` already provides the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates (and the OP has already obtained it)?

Comment: @whuber I don’t think this is a particularly good approach, but it is what OP asked. I’m not sure what you mean when you say glm provided the covariance matrix for parameters. I extract that via vcov but the variance OP seeks can’t be obtained directly from glm

Comment: @Demetri Pananos I see, thank you. Is it alright to use estimate = p1 - p2 instead of the diff() command you have? I'm not sure what that command is doing?

Comment: I don't understand why this approach isn't particularly good? I'm looking for a confidence interval on the difference between two probabilites - the probability of success when x=0 and the probability of success when x=1. If you would advocate for a different approach, please let me know.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I think that diff() command must be looking at the difference between the estimated probabilities. In that case, since x is binary, I think I can just take beta_1. No need to use this function.

Comment: @StatsSorceress  That initial `diff` command is taking the difference in the probabilities.  Honestly, this approach is overkill.  You have a binary outcome with a binary group indicator.  The easiest thing to do would be to do a test of proportions and get a confidence interval.  I'm all for "all tests are just regressions" but this seems particularly overkill to me.

Comment: @StatsSorceress $\beta_1$ is not the probability on the log odds scale, it is the log odds ratio.  You need a direct estimate of the difference in probability one way or another.  This is but one way to do it.

Comment: This rule is also (better?) known as "Gauss' law of error propagaton". It should be noted, though, that this is not an equality, but an approximation. I would thus suggest to replace the equality sign with an approximate sign (`\approx` in LaTeX).

Answer (score 7):

There are two principal approaches:

1. Estimate the *variance* $\hat{\sigma}^2$ of $\theta=p_{x1}-p_{x0}$ and assume that $\theta$ is normally distributed. Then the confidence interval is $\pm z_{1-\alpha/2} \hat{\sigma}$, where $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the quantile of the standard normal distribution (`qnorm(1-alpha/2)` in R), which is 1.96 for a 95% interval ($\alpha=0.05$).
2. Directly estimate a non-parametric (and possibly non-symmetrc) confidence interval with the bootstrap method.

The variance for method 1. can be estimated in different ways. One is the solution based on Gauss' error propagation law [suggested by @demetri-pananos](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/539792/244807). Another method would be the Jackknife, which consists in estimating the parameter $\theta_{(i)}$ $n$ times, each time with one observable left out, and compute the Jackknife Variance therefrom:
\begin{align}
\sigma_{JK} &= \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\theta_{(i)}-\theta_{(.)}\Big)^2}\\
 \mbox{ with }&\quad \theta_{(.)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_{(i)} \nonumber
\end{align}

Method 2. is similar to the Jackknife, but the parameter is estimated several times from observables drawn *with replacement*. From these estimates, the confidence interval can be estimated in different ways. In comparative studies, the "Bias Corrected Accelerated Bootstrap" had the best coverage probability. See section 6 of [this report](https://lionel.kr.hsnr.de/%7Edalitz/data/publications/fb03-tb-2017-01-en.pdf) for R code how to compute it and different comparative studies (section 5.2 of the same report explains the Jackknife and lists R code how to compute it).

Comment: A third possibility could be to use profile likelihood