# How to easily obtain the profile likelihood 95% confidence interval for a predicted value in a logistic regression model in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, biostatistics, profile-likelihood

I'm a fish biologist and we often use a logistic regression to estimate what we refer to as the L50, i.e. the length at which you expect one fish out of two (50%) to have developed gonads.

How to assess the uncertainty around the L50 estimate is not trivial.
Here is an example based on 95 sampled Walleye females that vary in length (LT) from 165 to 680 mm, of which 20 had developed gonads (MATURITE coded as 1) and thus, 75 had undeveloped gonads (MATURITE coded as 0).

The data are referred to as `saviMEGI14`, and the binary response variable `MATURITE` is analyzed according to the continuous independent variable `LT`. The logistic regression model is coded in R like this:

---

```
summary(m.saviMEGI14.LT <- glm(MATURITE ~ LT, 
   family = binomial, data = saviMEGI14))
```

---

Using the `dose.p()` function of the MASS package, I can easily get the estimation of the L50 and its associated SE:

---

```
library(MASS)

dose.p(m.saviMEGI14.LT)
```

p = 0.5

Dose = 491.9017

SE = 20.76949

---

And from these estimates, calculate the Wald-based CIs, simply multipling the SE by 1.96 and adding/substracting this value from the "Dose" estimate obtained, i.e. the L50 of 492 mm. The Wald CI would thus be [451, 532].

However, in such a relatively small sample size, the Wald CIs are not ideal because they are based on normal theory, so the default method in R, i.e. the profile likelihood function, should be used instead (see for instance [Royston 2007 The Stata Journal](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0700700305#:%7E:text=The%20technique%20known%20as%20profile,particularly%20useful%20in%20nonlinear%20models.))

I am aware that I can get the parameter estimates (central value and CI) for the Intercept and the LT by using the `confint()` function = profile likelihood or the `confint.default()` = Wald; but this does not allow me to compute the SE/CIs around the L50 from the logistic regression model.

To get the profile likelihood CIs around the L50 of 492 mm, I use the `predict()` function applied to the range of LT values by first creating a new data frame called below nd14_LT:

---

```
nd14_LT <- data.frame(LT=seq(from=165, to=680, 
              by=1))
```

---

and then get the predicted values for the nd14_LT data, asking also to obtain the associated predicted SE on the logit scale `(type="link")`:

---

```
pred14_LT <- predict(m.saviMEGI14.LT, nd14_LT, 
               type="link", se.fit=TRUE)
```

---

With the predicted values and their associated predicted SE, one can then convert them from the logit to the response scale and then find at which LT a probability of 0.5 is found for both the lower and upper CI bounds.

Doing so provide a profile likelihood-based CI of [457, 551], which is quite different than the Wald one [452, 532], especially for its upper portion.

Here is the plot showing the regression curve, as well as the central value and profile likelihood CIs (which is called a maturity ogive in fisheries science):

[image: MATURITY OGIVE]

All this to come up with this question:

How can someone obtain the lower and upper bounds of the profile likelihood function CI from a logistic regression conducted in R in a rapid manner?

With colleagues, we are using simulations to test different methods for the estimation of the uncertainty around the L50 (i.e., parametric and non-parametric bootstrapping, Fieller analytical method, credible intervals from the Bayesian approach, etc…) and we’d like to find a way to estimate the profile likelihood CI of a given dataset in a timely, valid manner.

Comment: Can you do Quantile (logistic) regression on your logistic regression model? Then you would just choose the 2.5 and 97.5 percentile curves to be drawn in addition to the 50 percentile curve. See https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1101100301

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ggjj11. I was aware about the quantile regression, but not the logistic quantile regression. It looks like the lrq package in R can allow such an analysis. I will definitely have a look at it. But regarding the profile likelhood CIs, do you have a suggestion to rapidly estimate the uncertainty without going through all the steps I've described? Thanks.

Comment: A warning: profile-likelihood CI aren't necessarily the default in R. IF the `MASS` package is installed then calling `confint()` on a `glm` or `nls` object will end up calling the corresponding `MASS` functions, which do use profile likelihoods. Otherwise, the Wald CI based on the covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates will be used.

Comment: In addition to what @EdM said: Do you have a reference that confirms that confidence intervals obtained by `predict` are profile likelihood intervals? I've never heard that term in that context. Thank you.

Comment: @Edm I've ran the same model on the same data, MASS being installed, but not loaded into active R session, and use first the confint() and obtain the message "Waiting for profiling to be done..." indicating that profile likelihood CIs were computed. Using the confint.default() provided me with narrower CIs for the parameter estimates. I couldn't use dose.p(), as MASS was not loaded into R. After doing so, I've got the same results. But thanks for the warning note: someone who does not have MASS installed could get different result, but I don't know for this.

Comment: @COOLSerdash this example is of interest for parameter CIs (profile likelihood vs. Wald): https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/11/example-9-14-confidence-intervals-for-logistic-regression-models/ However, for predict(), people do not seem to be unanimous about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423325/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-logistic-regression So the short answer to your question: no, I don't have a reference for this. On the other hand, if the CI obtained with dose.p() is correct (Wald), the CI with predict() differ (see plot) = should be the profile likelihood CI?

Comment: @julienbio99 Gavin Simpson is pretty clear on this and confirms my suspicion: "`exp(confint(fit))` will give you either Wald or profile likelihood (depending on pkgs loaded) confidence intervals on the **parameters** of the model, not the fitted values of the model." So I'm pretty sure that what you're calculating based on `predict` are not profile likelihood-based confidence intervals. The paper linked by Geoffrey compares no less than 6 methods for calculating CIs of LD50 (or other quantiles).

Comment: @COOLSerdash thanks for these precisions. I will certainly look further into this. I'm a bit puzzled that the estimated CIs we get from a logistic regression in R are not that clear about what they are exactly. Thanks again for your input. I'm interested in the SE/CI of the fitted values from a logistic regression model, so I need to be sure that what I get from predict() is truly [put method here] based.

Comment: I think these are simply backtransformed Wald-based confidence intervals on the logit scale (see Hosmer DW, Lemeshow S, Sturdivant RX (2013): Applied Logistic Regression. 3rd ed. Wiley, page 17).

Comment: @COOLSerdash this would make sense. Estimated SE (se.fit=TRUE) on the logit scale are symmetrical, but will often produce asymmetrical SE (and thus CIs) on the response scale. I've produced the plot above by applying the method you've just described. This would likely mean that the dose.p() symmetrical SE on the response scale does not allow us to estimate the "true" Wald CI, but rather an approximation of it - at least the way I see it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534864/what-standard-errors-are-returned-with-predict-glm-type-response-se-fi logit scale is better for this.

Comment: The standard error of `dose.p` is based on the delta method. The resulting confidence interval could also be described as a Wald-based interval, but the standard error is estimated differently.

Comment: @COOLSerdash this helps clarify things. I'm now realizing that I was not obtaining Wald CIs with dose.p(), but the Delta method ones. Also, can you please point to "the paper linked by Geoffrey compares no less than 6 methods for calculating CIs of LD50 (or other quantiles)", as I haven't been able to trace it back. Thanks.

Comment: It's also a Wald-based interval. The standard errors returned by `predict(..., se.fit = TRUE)` are also based on the delta method. But the procedure to find the confidence interval for the LD50 is different. `dose.p` directly calculates the standard error for the LD50 while your procedure uses the pointwise confidence limits around the curve. It may be interesting to compare the performance of both procedures. Based on the paper by Paige et al. (2011), I suspect both will be surpassed by the more sophisticated methods mentioned therein (e.g. the saddlepoint method).

Comment: Excellent. Things are definitely starting to get clearer. Thanks @COOLSerdash for your input and the reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My collaborator Rafael de Andrade Moral has written a R function that allows to estimate the uncertainty for L50 estimates according to 13 different methods, including the profile-likelihood method. We used this R function in our recently-published paper in Fisheries Research:

[Monitoring reproduction in fish: Assessing the adequacy of ogives and the predicted uncertainty of their L50 estimates for more reliable biological inferences](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165783623002564?dgcid=rss_sd_all)

to evaluate the coverage probability of different approaches, such as the Delta method, non-parametric bootstrapping and Fieller (1944)'s analytical approach. The profile-likehood method did pretty good but the Monte Carlo approach with BCa interval led to the best nominal coverage for the simulated dataset that we have analyzed.

The R scripts for the profile-likelihood method (and others) to assess uncertainty in the L50 (or else such as the L95) is available at:

https://github.com/rafamoral/L50/blob/main/confint_L.R

The supplementary material of our MS contains information on how to use the confint_L() function.

Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I see you mentioned the Fieller method in your original post.  Perhaps you were referring to the solution I provided below.

Here is a great [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41415556) on the topic. Using a logistic regression with a logit link function you can model the proportion of fish as a function of length, with $\lambda:=$LD50.  Based on the asymptotic normality of

$$ \frac{(\hat{\beta}_0 + \lambda\hat{\beta}_1)-\text{ln}\big(\frac{0.5}{1-0.5}\big)}{\sqrt{\hat{\text{se}}_{0}^2 + \lambda^2\hat{\text{se}}_1^2 + 2\lambda\hat{\text{cov}}_{01}}}$$

a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval is found by identifying the set of $\lambda$ that satisfy

$$ \frac{\left[(\hat{\beta}_0 + \lambda\hat{\beta}_1)-\text{ln}\big(\frac{0.5}{1-0.5}\big)\right]^2}{\hat{\text{se}}_{0}^2 + \lambda^2\hat{\text{se}}_1^2 + 2\lambda\hat{\text{cov}}_{01}}<z_{\alpha}^2$$

where $\hat{\text{se}}_{0}$ is the estimated standard error of $\hat{\beta}_0$, $\hat{\text{se}}_{1}$ is the estimated standard error of $\hat{\beta}_1$, and $\hat{\text{cov}}_{01}$ is the estimated covariance between $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$.  This works well even in small sample sizes and is a much better normal approximation than a Wald interval for $\lambda$ based on an identity link using the dose.p() output.  The confidence interval above can be calculated using standard output from the logistic regression without calling dose.p(), and should perform similarly to the likelihood ratio CI you are interested in.  The only part that would require some work is numerically inverting the quantity above.  You can create a sequence of values for $\lambda$, evaluate the quantity above for each value of $\lambda$, and identify those values that satisfy the inequality.

A great way to visualize this is to define and plot the following functions
$$H(\lambda)=1-\Phi\Bigg(\frac{(\hat{\beta}_0 + \lambda\hat{\beta}_1)-\text{ln}\big(\frac{0.5}{1-0.5}\big)}{\sqrt{\hat{\text{se}}_{0}^2 + \lambda^2\hat{\text{se}}_1^2 + 2\lambda\hat{\text{cov}}_{01}}}\Bigg)$$

$$H^{\text{-}}(\lambda)=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{(\hat{\beta}_0 + \lambda\hat{\beta}_1)-\text{ln}\big(\frac{0.5}{1-0.5}\big)}{\sqrt{\hat{\text{se}}_{0}^2 + \lambda^2\hat{\text{se}}_1^2 + 2\lambda\hat{\text{cov}}_{01}}}\Bigg)$$

\begin{eqnarray}
C(\lambda)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
H(\lambda) & \text{if } \lambda\le \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}) \\
 &  \nonumber\\
 H^{\text{-}}(\lambda)  & \text{if } \lambda\ge \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}). \end{array}  \right.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}.

where $\hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y})$ is the estimate of LD50 based on the observed data.  $C(\lambda)$ is called a confidence curve and depicts p-values and confidence intervals of all levels.  In small sample sizes the performance of this interval might be improved by referencing a $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom instead of a standard normal distribution.

If you are still interested in the likelihood ratio test you can create a similar confidence curve:

$$p:=\text{logit}^{-1}({\beta}_0 + \lambda{\beta}_1)$$
$$L(\beta_0,\beta_1)\propto \prod_{i=1}^n \text{logit}^{-1}({\beta}_0 + x_i{\beta}_1)^{y_i}\times[1-\text{logit}^{-1}({\beta}_0 + x_i{\beta}_1)]^{1-y_i}$$
$$\text{LR}=\frac{L(\tilde{\beta}_0,\tilde{\beta}_1)}{L(\hat{\beta}_0,\hat{\beta}_1)}$$
where $\tilde{\beta}_0$ and $\tilde{\beta}_1$ are estimates calculated under the restricted null space for $\lambda$.

\begin{eqnarray}
H(\lambda)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\big[1-F_{\chi^2_1}\big(-2\text{log(LR)}\big)\big]/2 & \text{if } \lambda\le \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}) \\
 &  \nonumber\\
 \big[1+F_{\chi^2_1}\big(-2\text{log(LR)}\big)\big]/2  & \text{if } \lambda\gt \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}). \end{array}  \right.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}.

\begin{eqnarray}
C(\lambda)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
H(\lambda) & \text{if } \lambda\le \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}) \\
 &  \nonumber\\
 1-H(\lambda)  & \text{if } \lambda\ge \hat{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{y}). \end{array}  \right.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

where $F_{\chi^2_1}$ is the CDF of a chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom.  Because the likelihood ratio confidence interval requires profiling nuisance parameters it is almost as computationally intensive as iterative methods such as bootstrap and Monte Carlo approaches.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey Johnson for the suggestion to what I understand to be a modification of Fieller (1944) analytical method. Our goal, however, is to get more commonly-used profile likelihood function-based CIs from R, on top of those of Wald, to compare them with those obtained with a Bayesian approach, and iterative procedures, such as parametric and non-parametric bootstrapping. All this through simulations for statistical comparisons of different effect and sample sizes. Computing profile likelihood-based CIs manually is not a option. And this thus needs to be straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good (and possible sole) example of what we have in mind to contrast different methods (here: Fieller, non-parametric bootstrapping and Monte Carlo algorithm) to assess the uncertainty around the L50 in fish: https://spo.nmfs.noaa.gov/sites/default/files/13roafis.pdf We'd like to test a broader range of methods, mostly to be able to tell: "do the more simple, non-interative procedures such as the profile-likelihood function, allow us to properly conduct statisticals test about the L50?".

Comment: I am more familiar with SAS, but I'll continue looking to find a ready-made R function for profile likelihood ratio confidence limits for LD50.  It might be that you will need to write your own R function to produce the confidence interval, and call this function within a simulation to assess its performance over many samples.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053542/confidence-intervals-for-lethal-dose-ld-for-logistic-regression-in-r) is a related thread on stackoverflow.  One of the answers offers a drc package, but I think this produces the standard Wald interval.

Comment: [@julienbio99](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/338493/julienbio99), you might be able to improve the performance of the Fieller method by referencing a t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom instead of a standard normal distribution and show that this works as well or better than the iterative methods.  The likelihood ratio method is almost as computationally intensive as the iterative methods because of the profiling (re-estimating nuisance parameters under the restricted null space).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey for sharing those references and ideas. Really appreciated. I've also found the following R package that seems to have been specifically designed to use profile likelihoods: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ProfileLikelihood/ProfileLikelihood.pdf but I need to figure out if it's only for model parameter (Beta) or if it can assess the uncertainty in the fitted values too. If not, developing our own codes will be our best guess. Thanks again. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR @kjetilbhalvorsen explains how to compute confidence intervals based on the profile likelihood in [Confidence interval for difference between two predicted probabilities in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/411175/237901). The entire thread is worth reading as it describes several methods to compute confidence intervals. I summarize the profile likelihood method briefly and then apply it to calculate a CI for the median lethal dose, LD50, on the tobacco budworms dataset. See Section 7.2 of *Modern Applied Statistics with S* by Venables and Ripley.

Let $\theta(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ be a scalar function of the model parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. Then the profile likelihood of $\theta$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_P(\theta) = \max_{\theta:\theta(\boldsymbol{\beta})=\theta}L(\boldsymbol{\beta})
\end{aligned}
$$
where $L(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is the likelihood. For the dose-response example, $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0,\beta_1)$ but the theory — and the R code — are straightforward to extend to more parameters. The LD50, the dose expected to kill 50% of individuals, is the point where the log-odds of survival are equal to zero: $\theta = -\beta_0/\beta_1$.

```r
x <- budworm$x # dose
y <- budworm$y # survival (0 or 1)

# The LD50 (dose that is expected to kill 50% of individuals) is defined as
# the point where the log-odds of survival are equal to zero.
theta <- function(beta0, beta1) {
  -beta0 / beta1
}

# The negative log-likelihood of the logistic regression model
# with an intercept and one predictor x.
negloglik_lrm <- function(beta0, beta1) {
  prob <- plogis(beta0 + beta1 * x)
  -sum(dbinom(y, 1, prob, log = TRUE))
}

# Fit a simple linear regression to find reasonable starting values.
initialize_betas <- function(x, y) {
  betas <- coef(lm(y ~ x))
  list(beta0 = betas[1], beta1 = betas[2])
}
```

The crux of the method is to profile the likelihood, ie, to maximize the likelihood over a grid of $\theta$ values. For a fixed $\theta$ we find $\max L(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ over the set $\left\{\boldsymbol{\beta}:\theta(\boldsymbol{\beta})=\theta\right\}$.

```r
# Minimize the negative log-likelihood instead of maximizing the likelihood
model <- bbmle::mle2(negloglik_lrm, start = initialize_betas(x, y))

# nlp = negative profile log-likelihood
grid <- profile_negloglik(model)
grid
#> # A tibble: 201 × 2
#>    theta   npl
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  1.65  141.
#>  2  1.67  140.
#>  3  1.68  139.
#>  4  1.70  138.
#>  5  1.71  137.
#>  6  1.73  136.
#>  7  1.74  135.
#>  8  1.75  134.
#>  9  1.77  133.
#> 10  1.78  132.
#> # … with 191 more rows
```

Now that we have calculated the profile likelihood for $\theta$ at a grid of values, it remains to find a subset of those to represent a confidence interval.

Under regularity conditions (which mean the log likelihood is well approximated by a quadratic function), the ratio likelihood test states that under the null hypothesis $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\log\frac{L(\widehat{\theta})}{L(\theta_0)} \sim \chi^2_p
\end{aligned}
$$
where $p$ is the number of parameters $\theta$, $\widehat{\theta}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) and $\chi^2_p$ is the [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $p$ degrees of freedom. This is the value at which the (profile) likelihood is minimized.

By inverting the hypothesis test we get a 100(1-$\theta$)% confidence interval (or region) for $\theta$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\{\theta:2\log\frac{L(\widehat{\theta})}{L(\theta)}<\chi^2_{p,(1-\alpha)}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the budworms example, the LD50 $\theta$ is a scalar, so $p=1$ and we can find the profile likelihood 95% and 99% confidence intervals numerically:

```r
#>   conf.level conf.low conf.high      nll
#> 1       0.95 2.415057  3.084742 113.6548
#> 2       0.99 2.312052  3.195448 115.0515
```

[image]

I also use the `MASS:dose.p` function to compute the Wald 95% and 99% confidence intervals. (See R code attached.)

```r
data.frame(
  conf.level,
  conf.low = dose.hat + dose.se * qnorm((1 - conf.level) / 2),
  conf.high = dose.hat - dose.se * qnorm((1 - conf.level) / 2)
)
#>   conf.level conf.low conf.high
#> 1       0.95 2.422786  3.071986
#> 2       0.99 2.320789  3.173983
```

In this example, the profile and the Wald confidence intervals for $\theta$ agree well.

*References*

In addition to @kjetilbhalvorsen's posts about profile likelihood, I'm also reading "In All Likelihood: Statistical Modelling And Inference Using Likelihood" by Yudi Pawitan. This book explains the theory in great detail and with many examples. (Not about budworms though.)

---

R code to compute profile likelihood confidence intervals:

```r
library("MASS")
library("tidyverse")

# Compute negative log-likelihood-based intervals for a scalar parameter theta
# at the specified alpha levels.
# This implementation is based on the program `li.r` for computing likelihood
# intervals which accompanies the book "In All Likelihood" by Yudi Pawitan.
# https://www.meb.ki.se/sites/yudpaw/book/
confint_negloglik <- function(theta, nll, conf.level = 0.95) {
  nll_min <- min(nll)
  
  # 2*{ log L(theta_mle) - log L(theta) } < qchisq(df=1,p=1-alpha)
  nll_cut <- nll_min + qchisq(conf.level, 1) / 2
  theta_mle <- mean(theta[nll == nll_min])

  theta_below <- theta[theta < theta_mle]
  if (length(theta_below) < 2) {
    conf.low <- min(theta)
  } else {
    nll.below <- nll[theta < theta_mle]
    conf.low <- approx(nll.below, theta_below, xout = nll_cut)$y
  }

  theta_above <- theta[theta > theta_mle]
  if (length(theta_above) < 2) {
    conf.high <- max(theta)
  } else {
    nll.above <- nll[theta > theta_mle]
    conf.high <- approx(nll.above, theta_above, xout = nll_cut)$y
  }

  data.frame(conf.level, conf.low, conf.high, nll = nll_cut)
}

grid_params <- function(model, pts = 100) {
  seq_range <- function(x, n) {
    seq(min(x), max(x), len = n)
  }
  # Use the confidence intervals to find reasonable ranges for the betas.
  range_betas <- bbmle::confint(bbmle::profile(model))
  expand_grid(
    # Create a grid (= an outer product) for beta0 and beta1
    beta0 = seq_range(range_betas["beta0", ], pts),
    beta1 = seq_range(range_betas["beta1", ], pts)
  ) %>%
    # For each point in the grid, compute the parameter of interest theta
    # and the negative log-likelihood of the model. Both are functions of
    # the regression coefficients beta0 and beta1.
    mutate(
      theta = theta(beta0, beta1),
      nll = map2_dbl(beta0, beta1, negloglik_lrm)
    )
}

profile_negloglik <- function(profile, bins = 201) {
  profile %>%
    grid_params() %>%
    group_by(
      # Subdivide the observed range of theta into many small intervals.
      cut_interval(theta, bins),
      .drop = TRUE
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      # For each interval, find its midpoint as well as the minimum of
      # the negative log-likelihood. This is the negative profile
      # log-likelihood (npl).
      theta = (min(theta) + max(theta)) / 2,
      npl = min(nll)
    ) %>%
    select(
      theta, npl
    )
}

plot_profile <- function(grid, confint) {
  grid %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(theta, npl)
    ) +
    geom_line(
      linewidth = 1
    ) +
    geom_segment(
      aes(
        x = conf.low, xend = conf.high,
        y = nll, yend = nll,
        color = factor(conf.level)
      ),
      inherit.aes = FALSE,
      data = confint,
      linewidth = 1
    ) +
    guides(
      color = guide_legend(title = "confidence level")
    )
}

# Tobacco budworms survival data. See `MASS::dose.p`.
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
numalive <- 20 - numdead

budworm <- list(
  x = c(rep(ldose, numdead), rep(ldose, numalive)),
  y = c(rep(0, sum(numdead)), rep(1, sum(numalive)))
)

conf.level <- c(0.95, 0.99)

x <- budworm$x
y <- budworm$y

# The negative log-likelihood of the logistic regression model
# with an intercept and one predictor x.
negloglik_lrm <- function(beta0, beta1) {
  prob <- plogis(beta0 + beta1 * x)
  -sum(dbinom(y, 1, prob, log = TRUE))
}

# The LD50 (dose that is expected to kill 50% of individuals) is defined as
# the point where the log-odds of survival are equal to zero.
theta <- function(beta0, beta1) {
  -beta0 / beta1
}

# Fit a simple linear regression to find reasonable starting values.
initialize_betas <- function(x, y) {
  betas <- coef(lm(y ~ x))
  list(beta0 = betas[1], beta1 = betas[2])
}

# Minimize the negative log-likelihood instead of maximizing the likelihood
model <- bbmle::mle2(negloglik_lrm, start = initialize_betas(x, y))

profile <- bbmle::profile(model)
grid <- profile_negloglik(model)
grid

# Profile confidence intervals for the betas parameters and for theta
ci.betas <- bbmle::confint(profile)
ci.betas
ci.theta <- confint_negloglik(grid$theta, grid$npl, conf.level)
ci.theta

plt <- plot_profile(grid, ci.theta)
plt +
  labs(
    x = expression(paste(θ, "=", -beta[0] / beta[1])),
    y = "negative profile log-likelihood",
    title = "Negative profile log-likelihood for LD50"
  )

model <- glm(
  y ~ x,
  family = binomial
)

dose.p(model)
dose.hat <- 2.747386
dose.se <- 0.1656153

# Wald confidence interval
data.frame(
  conf.level,
  conf.low = dose.hat + dose.se * qnorm((1 - conf.level) / 2),
  conf.high = dose.hat - dose.se * qnorm((1 - conf.level) / 2)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer and the codes provided. Really appreciated.